# Is there any solution to solve parsing error in sqoop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to import data from SQL Server to HDFS using Sqoop . While running the command on the edge node I am getting below parsing error.

```
$ sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://XXXXXX/ARA_RNA' --username XXXXXX --password XXXXXX--table dbo.test_log --m 1;
20/08/14 06:43:29 INFO util.log: Logging initialized @850ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
    20/08/14 06:43:30 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7-mapr-1904-r1
    20/08/14 06:43:30 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
    20/08/14 06:43:30 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --p
    20/08/14 06:43:30 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: LTJ33_hy
    20/08/14 06:43:30 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --table
    20/08/14 06:43:30 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: dbo.test_log
    20/08/14 06:43:30 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --m
    20/08/14 06:43:30 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: 1
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but shouldn't all of the connection string be enclosed in the single quote?

Comment: I'm 100% sure that it is either `-m` (one dash) or `--num-mappers` (two dashes) for the number of mappers.

Comment: add --target-dir HDFSlocation

Comment: See the [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_literal) for argument